# UIScrollView setContentOffset while animating?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uikit

If I set the `contentOffset` (without animation) of a `UIScrollView` while it's scrolling, the scroll view jumps to the correct offset, but then continues scrolling. How do I prevent it from continuing scrolling?

Comment: Try the method described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/987991/663476

Answer (score -1):

you can try to reset the scrolling by calling another `setContentOffset` with animated:YES

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:targetPoint animated:FALSE];
[scrollView setContentOffset:targetPoint animated:TRUE];
```