# How do I make a UITableView stop scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I don't mean that I want to disable scrolling. I want to be able to programmatically tell the table to immediately stop moving (but then it should still be scrollable after than). Is this possible?

Comment: Try looking at this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986392/programmatically-force-a-uiscrollview-to-stop-scrolling-for-sharing-a-table-vie
This could also work:
[tableView setContentOffset:tableView.contentOffset animated:NO];
Hope it helps. :)

Comment: This title is sort of misleading.

Comment: @JonathanKing: I don't think it is at all. There's a big difference between "how do I make a table stop scrolling" and "how do I prevent a table from scrolling". It's also why questions have a title and a longer description to go with it.

Comment: @MusiGenesis Good point, although I would say a title such as "How do I make a UITableView stop moving during scroll animation" or even use just replacing 'scrolling' with 'moving' (which you have written in your description) would be more accurate.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

A `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. If you tell it to scroll to its current position, it will stop scrolling so this should work for you:

```
[tableView setContentOffset:tableView.contentOffset animated:NO];
```

Comment: Well, that sort of worked, but it only works to stop the table from scrolling. If the table doesn't have enough rows to actually scroll, if I pull down it will still bounce a little bit, which triggers the scrollViewDidScroll: call, which I'm trying to prevent from happening by stopping the scrolling

Comment: In that case you should disable scrolling if the table view does not have enough rows.

Comment: Note that you MUST use the method indicated in this answer, setting the `contentOffset` property directly will not cancel any scrolling animations that  are in progress.

Answer (score 22):

Bind your table view to a variable called `tableView`, then with the following line you can disable the scrolling in Objective-C:

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Swift version:

```
tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Set it to `YES` (`true`), if you want it to be scrollable again.

Answer (score 8):

set `tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false;`

Comment: How does this answer anything to do with the question?

Comment: @Rambatino: I think the user was responding to my comment under the selected answer about also preventing the bouncing, although this would have been better as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using table view controller,follow below steps

1. Select table view controller on storyboard
2. Go to attribute inspector->scrollview
3. Uncheck the scrolling enabled